# Why is calling a function with angle brackets before it valid syntax in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Vanilla JS allows angle brackets to be used on function calls for some reason, but it changes the behaviour. It most certainly is not generics, as well, JS isnt statically typed.

```js
let x = "ok";
console.log<"you wont see this">("And you wont see this either");
```

just returns false and never outputs anything to the console. Why is this valid syntax and what exactly does it do?

Comment: It is not a function call, it is a comparison operators (`<`, `>`, <=, >=, ...) in your case.

Comment: what puzzles me here is this: `let x = "ok";`

Comment: What's confusing about the let statement?

Comment: @Phix the fact that it doesn't seem to be related at all with the next line of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a chain of comparison operators. Comparison operators are all [left-associative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence#table), so they are evaluated left-to-right.

What happens is:

- assess if `console.log` is less than `"you wont see this"`; the result is `false` (other operators will also return `false` though)
- assess that `false` (the result from the above) is greater than `("And you wont see this either")` – which is essentially just a string, the parentheses are irrelevant in this case; the result is still `false`.

Nothing is ever logged in the console because `console.log` is never called.